# WPF - Using grid in listbox item

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, grid, listviewitem

To begin with I am beginner to WPF, so please explain it with simple words.

I want to make custom listview item with quite a lot of elements. I decided to use grid to align it nicely. Unfortunately when i tried to see if everything is resizing ok, the background(listview item) resizes while grid doesnt. I think it is because grid isnt properly attached to listview item. So question is how can i attach grid to listview item so I can scale content properly?

Here is code (its a bit messy because of my tries to resolve problem):

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="SurfManager.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="503" Width="933">
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded"/>
</Window.Triggers>
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Obecne Wypożyczenia" Background="White" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="#FF8C8E94" OpacityMask="White">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ListView BorderThickness="0" Height="440">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn/>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                    <ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF2AD618" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF6CFF5D" Offset="0.582"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </ListViewItem.Background>
                        <Grid Height="82.96" Width="859.733">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="41*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="42*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="180*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="283*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="387*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="140*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Content="Imię:"  Margin="8.001,10,0,38" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                            <Label Content="Nazwisko:"  Margin="8.001,5.451,0,3.529" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                            <Label Content="Początek:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0.978,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="27.96" Width="59.733" Grid.Column="2"/>
                            <Label Content="Koniec:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0.978,1.92,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="33" Grid.Row="1" Width="48.107" Grid.Column="2"/>
                            <Label Content="Pozostało" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="25.96" Width="61.79" Grid.Column="3"/>
                            <Label Content="Cena:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,8.96,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Height="25.96" Width="39.204" Grid.Column="3"/>
                            <Label Content="Deska" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,5.02,0,0" Height="25.96" Width="41.853" Grid.Column="4"/>
                            <Label Content="Żagiel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="9.746,6.02,0,0" Height="25.96" Width="42.107" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ListViewItem>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Baza Klientow">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Administracja sprzętem" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="19.96" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="144.32" Margin="-2,-2,-7,0">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Your Grid is not going to resize when you've specified explicit widths.

Comment: Which ones you mean? those at row/column definitions or at <Grid Height="82.96" Width="859.733">? I deleted the latter one but it changed nothing.

Comment: could you post a screen of your expected result?

Comment: are you sure your listview set both  <ListView.View> and   <ListViewItem>

Comment: @pushpraj well its the same as the xaml(except i havent copied </Window> at end i will edit) i posted I just want for all elements inside to scale

Comment: @Rang sorry it's my first attempt at wpf so i have no idea what you are talking about and that's mostly why i pasted xaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what you need

add this style resource in your list view and remove width from your grid.

```
    <ListView BorderThickness="0"
                Height="440">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
```

by modifying default teplate from list view item will make the content re sizable

also remove the following as not necessary

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn/>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

Answer (score 1):

ListView is often used like this:

use binding:

```
<ListView BorderThickness="0" >
      <ListView.View>
              <GridView>
                 <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                 <GridViewColumn Header="Address" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Address}"/>
               </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

or like this:

```
 <ListView BorderThickness="0" >
     <ListViewItem>
          <Grid >
             ....
          </Grid>
      </ListViewItem>
  </ListView>
```

are you sure you need set both `ListView.View` and `ListViewItem` ? It will looks like :
[image]

btw,you should not set grid's width and height,most important thing is your grid's content looks confused. you must set those lables in correct Grid.Col or Grid.Row, why you set ColumnSpan/RowSpan ? If you are sure it's correct?